# What does jenkins look into the project to start unit tests

Tags: jenkins

I have looked into jenkins tutorials and all most all of them mention that we should provide with the URL to the git repo.

Fine.

But once jenkins has an access to the git repo, what part of project does it look into to figure out which tests should be run or wether to run them at all etc ? Is it some configuration file in the repo ?

Comment: it doesn't "just know"... You have to use maven or ant to run tests in jenkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess that depends on what kind of project your repo is. If I understand the question correctly. The provided url gives Jenkins the information to do a **git clone url** which checks out the project in Jenkins workspace.

Then according to the type, lets say it's a Maven-project, you fill in the goals you'd like Jenkins to run locally. Usually **clean test**. It is then run at top level, root of the project, guessing it will find a pom.xml there. If not you'll have to tell it where to look.

A more clearer answer would perhaps be easier if you told what kind of project you'd like to build.